# Installing MathTime Professional 2 on El Capitan

Tags: installing, mactex, mtpro

I just purchased `mtpro2` (the complete version), and I am trying to install it on a Mac using the latest El Capitan. I followed the instructions on this website: http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/. I tried the command

`./mtpro2-texlive.sh -i mtp2fonts.zip.tpm`,

and this is the output I got:

```
Unpacking mtp2fonts.zip.tpm.
find: /usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-local/: No such file or directory
find: /usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-local/: No such file or directory
Copying files.
```

It asked for my password, I inserted, and it said:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
   cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory

Installing MathTime Professional 2.
  > running texhash
  > updating map references
chmod: /usr/local/share/texmf/: No such file or directory
  > editing updmap.cfg
  > updating TeX Live databases
TeX Live updated; checking that MTPro2 works...
There appears to have been an error in installation.
Consult the log file for more information.
```

I have no clue what to do, but I heard it happened some major changes along with El Capitan. Maybe the `mtpro2-texlive.sh` (the installer) needs some changes? Do any of you have a better way of installing it?

Help, please :)

Comment: Welcome! What's in the shell script? It does not look like an El Captain problem from what you've posted but it is hard to say without knowing more. Do you have MacTeX 2015 installed? Did you install the full version or only the basic version? (I'm wondering why it is looking for `2015basic`.  But it shouldn't be looking for `2015basic/texmf-local` as far as I know. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` would be my guess as to where it should be installing.

Comment: You can download the shell script here: http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/mtpro2-texlive.tar.gz

Comment: I just have the BasicTex, could that affect it?

Comment: Maybe TEXMFLOCAL is in a different default location for the Basic scheme.

Comment: Try `sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)` and then run the installer again. I don't think the shell script is doing what it should and it is making assumptions which are just as likely false as not. (Maybe the instructions tell you what to do, but this is really not necessary - the script could easily get this right.)

Answer (score 2):

The installation script does not take elementary precautions. It should check whether the directories it wants to install into exist and create them if not. In fact, it doesn't even need to do this, it can just use a command which says, in effect, 'make sure this hierarchy of directories exist for me' using `mkdir -p`. Or, better, it should probably be using `install` to ensure correct permissions.

The problem is that if `TEXMFLOCAL` doesn't exist, it doesn't create it. It just tries to copy files there using `cp` and, since the destination is non-existent, the OS complains that it cannot send anything to a non-existent place.

Running

```
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)
```

before running the installer will ensure that the relevant directories exist. I would not fully trust the script without checking it thoroughly, which I did not do. Therefore, I don't guarantee that there are not other quirks which might prove problematic. But this should workaround this particular problem.

Comment: I'm the person who made the installer script. The mkdir command has now been incorporated into it. On a more general note, the installer script is now hosted on Github so if anyone finds another problem and updates the script those updates can be pulled in.

Comment: https://github.com/jamespfennell/mathtime-installer

Comment: @JamesFennell Good to know.