# installing MathTime Professional 2 Lite on MacOS Sierra

Tags: installing, mac, mtpro

I have MacTeX-2016 installed on MacOS Sierra.

Could someone please list the steps that I can follow in order to install MathTime Professional 2 Lite? I would be grateful for any help.

A related question for reference:
[Installing MathTime Professional 2 on El Capitan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279882/installing-mathtime-professional-2-on-el-capitan)

Comment: I don't think there are really differences: use `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`

Comment: Thanks @egreg Are you referring to the steps listed on http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/ ? Sorry but which path is that?

Comment: No, don't follow those instructions, which are for Linux boxes with their own TeX distributions.

Comment: Please download `TeXLive2014+Changes.pdf.zip` from [my download site](https://herbs.github.io). There is a section in that document about installing fonts in recent versions of TeX Live (installed by MacTeX).

Comment: Thanks @HerbSchulz Should I also download the `Eps-Tiff-Conversion2014+.pdf.zip' document?

Comment: Not really needed for font installation, but it might be informative. Actually you night already have in `/Applications/TeX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions at

http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/

worked for me.